# conda install -c conda-forge paraview: failed to install paraview

Tags: python, installation, conda, spyder, paraview

Failed to install paraview through conda in the base environment even though it installs fine in any newly created environments. The issue is, my spyder is present in base and can't be installed in any other env.
[it keeps trying to find a way to install but fails everytime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzqhQ.png)

I need both of these in the same env to make it work. I have already added their paths to PYTHONPATH and PATH but no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that paraview is a large package with a lot of dependencies.  Not all of those dependencies can be satisfied while keeping the base Anaconda installation intact because the base environment already contains so many packages.

The solution is to install both spyder and paraview into a new environment.

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.10.* spyder paraview --channel conda-forge
```

To use spyder, you need to activate the new environment before running the `spyder` command.

```
conda activate myenv
spyder
```